# searching for "university kind"  free online course about OPENGL

Tags: opengl

I know there are a lot of free university courses, but I'm trying to find one about OpenGL.
Do you know where can I find one, online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the website, but there appears to be free courses on Connexions:

http://cnx.org/content/expanded_browse_authors?letter=P&author=professorpayne

Personally, I learned a lot from NeHe:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Edit: Actually, don't use NeHe. Most of what it teaches you has been deprecated. I'm not sure there is a free university course for modern OpenGL, but [this list of resources](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/32917/19855]) is fantastic.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should learn 3 things, to work with OpenGL:

- basic Linear Algebra and 3D geometry (vector spaces, linear
  transformations, normals ...)
- triangle meshes and how they work, how to store them into "buffers"
- general programming and general math skills to use in shader programming

Try google for that. When you learn it, then you can start to use OpenGL or DirectX or anything you want. It will be very simple for you.

BTW I really doubt that some university is going to "teach OpenGL". Maybe you can find courses about "hardware accelerated rasterization", which may cover different ideas and techniques, but definitly not "teach OpenGL".

Comment: something like this :
http://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/sclaroff/courses/cs480/

Answer (score 3):

I've very recently come across [Programming for Games / Graphics for Games / Game Techniques](http://research.ncl.ac.uk/game/mastersdegree/graphicsforgames/) from Newcastle Uni.
There's a series of course PDFs, source code for their framework, etc. All done using modern OpenGL (3.4) and written as clean and tidy code.

It's one of the best public game related OGL resources I've found yet.

Answer (score 1):

Udacity are launching an [Interactive Rendering course](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs291/). I'm guessing it's WebGL though. Not sure it's it's in JavaScript or has some Python bindings.