# Proper opengl learning curve + tools

Tags: c++, opengl

My first post here, so at first i would like to say HI to everyone!

Had a course of computer graphics at my uni and got interested with opengl. Unfortunatelly we used it with java + jogl + some funky frameworks from our lecturers which provided us with all texturing etc. Now i want to switch to c++, because as i noticed all the tutorials are written in it.

My question is about additional libraries. Google told me that "OpenGL SuperBible V Comprehensive Tutorial and Reference" by Richard S. Wright will be helpful for the learning process and in the book they use GLEW + GLtools. Are those proper tools or should i start with something else? Maybe some other books? [yes i used search for online courses and books here, but maybe you have some tested and up to date positions]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good resources for learning modern OpenGL (3.0 or later)?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/good-resources-for-learning-modern-opengl-3-0-or-later)

Comment: What are "proper tools"? How do you define that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are those proper tools or should i start with something else?

If you want to take a deeper look into what the frameworks from your lecturers do, the SuperBible does a very good job explaining all those basic things. There are also some good tutorials and references to useful libraries (like glm) if you want to start experimenting by yourself at [opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org/). So to answer your questions, yes the SuperBible is definitely one of the things you might want to read, although GLTools is probably something you will quickly get ahead off.

As for other references: use the search functions, there are a lot of these questions with good answers around already.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite toolkit so far is GLFW.  It's simple to use while fully featured and integrates well with OpenGL.  GLEW is a must for anything complex, as it will allow you to easily use extensions.

I'm not sure if this is a proper question, but I'll answer it anyways :)