# Is Opengl 2.x still usable?

Tags: opengl-es

i've used opengl core profile for a while now and i was wondering if it was possible to create a "decent" application (like a game/game engine) with good graphics. I have a machine which can run only OpenGl 2.1(raspberry pi3), i already know the advantages of core profile, but is Opengl 2.x still usable for today's standards?

Comment: OpenGL 2 only has relatively few aspects, that would stop this from happening. The fact that you use a raspberry pi is a bigger bottleneck.

Comment: So, because of this i am limited by the raspberry pi instead of Opengl 2.x? Are there some examples in which Legacy opengl is used?

Comment: Raspberry pi is **not** full OpenGL 2, it's ES2 and is therefore missing functionality.

Comment: OpenGL  ES 2.0 is actually still very common in the market as can be seen by computingfreak's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110431/opengl-es-versions-on-different-devices.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/is-learning-opengl-2-1-useless-today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you are very confused.

There is OpenGL ***ES*** 2.0, and there is *desktop* OpenGL 2.0 and 2.1. These are *very different things*, which run on entirely different platforms. ES runs on primarily mobile hardware, while desktop GL runs primarily on desktop hardware.

The [core/compatibility distinction](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types) only exists for desktop GL, not OpenGL ES.

Raspberry Pi, of any version, does not support desktop OpenGL *of any version*. It only supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

As for what you can do with ES 2.0, a lot. You'll find Raspberry Pi's GPU to be limiting from a performance point of view, but you will have access to basic shader functionality. You can do a lot with that.

Comment: So if i write a program using opengl es 2 i can run(with of course all the required tools to create an apk) it on android, or any type of machine equipped with an arm processor. Right?

Comment: @GabrieleVierti - wrong; the graphics API is only a part of what you need for portability; you also need to port sound, networking, windowing, and anything else platform-specific.